# Resolving conflict with urllib3 to install AWS elastic beanstalk CLI using anaconda on Macos?

Tags: python, macos, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, conda

I'm trying to install the cli for aws elastic beanstalk using `conda install -c davidbgonzalez awsebcli` but I keep running into this error:

```
/Users/deepak/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.23) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - awsebcli
  - urllib3
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Now this error appeared for many libraries- not just urllib3; but for each of those I was able to resolve by using either `conda uninstall` or `pip install --upgrade`. However, for urllib3, if I uninstall, the conda command itself doesn't work, as it says requests package not found, and if I update urllib3- it makes no difference, the conflict remains and I cant move forward with my awsebcli installation.

Help?

PS: I use a MacOS with conda 4.5.9 installation with python 2.7.14.
I tried a pip install awsebcli- and it installed properly, but I'm not able to locate the executable and thus not sure how to include it into the '$PATH' variable. So, I'm guessing I need to use conda install as that is the main python I use everywhere.

UPDATE:
this is the result of `conda info urllib3`

```
/Users/deepak/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.23) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)

urllib3 1.21.1 py27_0
---------------------
file name   : urllib3-1.21.1-py27_0.tar.bz2
name        : urllib3
version     : 1.21.1
build string: py27_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
size        : 151 KB
arch        : x86_64
constrains  : ()
date        : 2017-06-21
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
md5         : 57332c18a93a2d82131212d52a0bafbf
platform    : darwin
subdir      : osx-64
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64/urllib3-1.21.1-py27_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    certifi
    cryptography >=1.3.4
    idna >=2.0.0
    ipaddress
    pyopenssl >=0.14
    pysocks >=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7
    python 2.7*

urllib3 1.21.1 py36_0
---------------------
file name   : urllib3-1.21.1-py36_0.tar.bz2
name        : urllib3
version     : 1.21.1
build string: py36_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
size        : 153 KB
arch        : x86_64
constrains  : ()
date        : 2017-06-21
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
md5         : 676e7d5b7366f2636edde60a528dbb22
platform    : darwin
subdir      : osx-64
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64/urllib3-1.21.1-py36_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    certifi
    cryptography >=1.3.4
    idna >=2.0.0
    pyopenssl >=0.14
    pysocks >=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7
    python 3.6*

urllib3 1.21.1 py35_0
---------------------
file name   : urllib3-1.21.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
name        : urllib3
version     : 1.21.1
build string: py35_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
size        : 154 KB
arch        : x86_64
constrains  : ()
date        : 2017-06-21
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
md5         : 1c5e2fdfed928117f86c0a89c0b97b19
platform    : darwin
subdir      : osx-64
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64/urllib3-1.21.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    certifi
    cryptography >=1.3.4
    idna >=2.0.0
    pyopenssl >=0.14
    pysocks >=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7
    python 3.5*

urllib3 1.23 py35_0
-------------------
file name   : urllib3-1.23-py35_0.tar.bz2
name        : urllib3
version     : 1.23
build string: py35_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
size        : 152 KB
arch        : None
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
md5         : 7e349638ccb5faad1b2f4378657e969f
platform    : None
subdir      : osx-64
timestamp   : 1529348179047
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64/urllib3-1.23-py35_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    certifi
    cryptography >=1.3.4
    idna >=2.0.0
    pyopenssl >=0.14
    pysocks >=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7
    python >=3.5,<3.6.0a0

urllib3 1.23 py27_0
-------------------
file name   : urllib3-1.23-py27_0.tar.bz2
name        : urllib3
version     : 1.23
build string: py27_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
size        : 150 KB
arch        : None
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
md5         : 10fa8961318553993367293d607cd870
platform    : None
subdir      : osx-64
timestamp   : 1529348370587
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64/urllib3-1.23-py27_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    certifi
    cryptography >=1.3.4
    idna >=2.0.0
    ipaddress
    pyopenssl >=0.14
    pysocks >=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7
    python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0

urllib3 1.22 py35he002d57_0
---------------------------
file name   : urllib3-1.22-py35he002d57_0.tar.bz2
name        : urllib3
version     : 1.22
build string: py35he002d57_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
size        : 156 KB
arch        : None
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
md5         : caf79d85b6ad4c487988886198b7ad36
platform    : None
subdir      : osx-64
timestamp   : 1505923648539
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64/urllib3-1.22-py35he002d57_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    certifi
    cryptography >=1.3.4
    idna >=2.0.0
    pyopenssl >=0.14
    pysocks >=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7
    python >=3.5,<3.6.0a0

urllib3 1.23 py36_0
-------------------
file name   : urllib3-1.23-py36_0.tar.bz2
name        : urllib3
version     : 1.23
build string: py36_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
size        : 152 KB
arch        : None
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
md5         : f582f82965d2bbdd0ac3b5b034ee2af4
platform    : None
subdir      : osx-64
timestamp   : 1529348338677
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64/urllib3-1.23-py36_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    certifi
    cryptography >=1.3.4
    idna >=2.0.0
    pyopenssl >=0.14
    pysocks >=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7
    python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0

urllib3 1.23 py37_0
-------------------
file name   : urllib3-1.23-py37_0.tar.bz2
name        : urllib3
version     : 1.23
build string: py37_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
size        : 152 KB
arch        : None
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
md5         : 3cf975556522788681a2c6caf7a955ae
platform    : None
subdir      : osx-64
timestamp   : 1530723151837
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64/urllib3-1.23-py37_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    certifi
    cryptography >=1.3.4
    idna >=2.0.0
    pyopenssl >=0.14
    pysocks >=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7
    python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0

urllib3 1.22 py27hc3787e9_0
---------------------------
file name   : urllib3-1.22-py27hc3787e9_0.tar.bz2
name        : urllib3
version     : 1.22
build string: py27hc3787e9_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
size        : 153 KB
arch        : None
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
md5         : 5c91bc08e0a7c2cf3726fea8bc6c504e
platform    : None
subdir      : osx-64
timestamp   : 1505923615525
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64/urllib3-1.22-py27hc3787e9_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    certifi
    cryptography >=1.3.4
    idna >=2.0.0
    ipaddress
    pyopenssl >=0.14
    pysocks >=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7
    python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0

urllib3 1.22 py36h68b9469_0
---------------------------
file name   : urllib3-1.22-py36h68b9469_0.tar.bz2
name        : urllib3
version     : 1.22
build string: py36h68b9469_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
size        : 155 KB
arch        : None
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
md5         : 603417ae48ed5fa80d809dfb91c47f55
platform    : None
subdir      : osx-64
timestamp   : 1505923681524
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64/urllib3-1.22-py36h68b9469_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    certifi
    cryptography >=1.3.4
    idna >=2.0.0
    pyopenssl >=0.14
    pysocks >=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7
    python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0
```

I uninstalled cryptography and idna using pip uninstall, but the conflict doesn't go- i get the same error when I `conda install -c davidbgonzalez awsebcli`.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you already have a `urllib3` in your `conda` lib directory. Have you tried uninstalling `urlliub3` prior to attempting to install `awsebcli`?

At any rate, installation of the `awsebcli` using `conda` is **not** officially supported. Furthermore, `conda install -c davidbgonzalez awsebcli` installs a version of the `awsebcli` almost 2 years old.

> I tried a pip install awsebcli- and it installed properly, but I'm not able to locate the executable and thus not sure how to include it ...

Did you install it as `sudo`? If so, it would make it non-readable to your user (as it is not in your path). This is a common pitfall. I recommend using [virtualenv with `pip` for the sanest experience](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv). Let me know if this works.

Comment: I did pip install and it worked- although not with virtualenv. Thanks man